# position: fixed; not working when keyboard opened on kitkat

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, android-4.4-kitkat

I have 3 device 4.0.3 and twin 4.4 .

The following code working on 4.0.3 but position:fixed not working on kitkat when keyboard opened. (running on webview)

```
<style>
body
{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#footer {
    **position: fixed;**
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background:#99cc00;
    height:60px;
}

</style>
<center><input type="text" style="margin:100;"></center>
<div id="footer">
```

I found this entrys but not solved my problem.

[jQuery Mobile fixed footer is moving when the keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097663/jquery-mobile-fixed-footer-is-moving-when-the-keyboard-appears)

[window.resize due to virtual keyboard causes issues with jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879857/window-resize-due-to-virtual-keyboard-causes-issues-with-jquery-mobile)

[jQuery Mobile fixed footer is moving when the keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097663/jquery-mobile-fixed-footer-is-moving-when-the-keyboard-appears)

Answer (score 1):

Whats the stars there?
Try to set

```
position:fixed; 
bottom:0;
left:0;
```